# logstash input s3 not getting/returning any data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logstash, aws-sdk, logstash-configuration

I am using logstash on a local windows 7 machine and tring to pull some test data I have stored on an AWS s3 bucket called mylogging.data and the file is "myTempLog123345.log". Below is the config file for logstash that I run locally.

**01_input.conf**

```
input {
    s3 {
        access_key_id => "XXXXXXXXX"
        secret_access_key => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        bucket => "mylogging.data"
        codec => "plain"
        region => "eu-west-1"
        type => "s3"
        prefix => "/"
        use_ssl => true
        temporary_directory => "C:/logstash/testing-log-data/" 
    }
}

output {
    stdout {}
}
```

when I run `C:\logstash>bin\logstash agent -f \logstash\conf\01_input.conf --debug` this is the following output.

**output**

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
←[36mReading config file {:file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstas
h-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb", :level=>:debug, :line=>"318", :method=
>"local_config"}←[0m
←[36mCompiled pipeline code:
        @inputs = []
        @filters = []
        @outputs = []
        @periodic_flushers = []
        @shutdown_flushers = []

          @input_s3_1 = plugin("input", "s3", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "
access_key_id" => ("XXXXXXXXX") }, { "secret_access_key" => ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") }, { "bucket" => ("mylogging.data") }, { "codec
" => ("plain") }, { "region" => ("eu-west-1") }, { "type" => ("s3") }, { "prefix
" => ("/") }, { "use_ssl" => ("true") }, { "temporary_directory" => ("C:/logstas
h/testing-log-data/") }))

          @inputs << @input_s3_1

          @output_stdout_2 = plugin("output", "stdout")

          @outputs << @output_stdout_2

  def filter_func(event)
    events = [event]
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("filter received", :event => event.to_hash)
    events
  end
  def output_func(event)
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("output received", :event => event.to_hash)
    @output_stdout_2.handle(event)

  end {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-c
ore-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"37", :method=>"initialize"}←[0
m
←[36mPlugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"input",
:name=>"s3", :path=>"logstash/inputs/s3", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/vend
or/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin.rb", :line
=>"71", :method=>"lookup"}←[0m
←[36mPlugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"codec",
:name=>"plain", :path=>"logstash/codecs/plain", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstas
h/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin.rb",
 :line=>"71", :method=>"lookup"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"
/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/con
fig/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@access_key_id = "XXXXXXXXX" {:level
=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-jav
a/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@secret_access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems
/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>
"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@bucket = "mylogging.data" {:level=>:debug, :file=
>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/c
onfig/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF
-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-co
re-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init
"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@region = "eu-west-1" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"
/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/con
fig/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@type = "s3" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash
/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin
.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@prefix = "/" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstas
h/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixi
n.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@use_ssl = true {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logst
ash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mi
xin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@temporary_directory = "C:/logstash/testing-log
-data/" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash
-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_i
nit"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logst
ash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mi
xin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@credentials = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/log
stash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/
mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@sincedb_path = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/l
ogstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/confi
g/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@backup_to_bucket = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=
>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/c
onfig/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@backup_add_prefix = nil {:level=>:debug, :file
=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/
config/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@backup_to_dir = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/
logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/conf
ig/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@delete = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logst
ash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mi
xin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@interval = 60 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logsta
sh/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mix
in.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Inputs::S3/@exclude_pattern = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>
"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/co
nfig/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mPlugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"output",
 :name=>"stdout", :path=>"logstash/outputs/stdout", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/log
stash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin.
rb", :line=>"71", :method=>"lookup"}←[0m
←[36mPlugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"codec",
:name=>"line", :path=>"logstash/codecs/line", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/
vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin.rb", :
line=>"71", :method=>"lookup"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Codecs::Line/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/
logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/conf
ig/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Line charset=>
"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstas
h-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_
init"}←[0m
←[36mconfig LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@workers = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/log
stash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/config/
mixin.rb", :line=>"128", :method=>"config_init"}←[0m
Default settings used: Filter workers: 4
←[32mRegistering s3 input {:bucket=>"mylogging.data", :region=>"eu-west-1", :level=
>:info, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/local_gems/a8565979/logstash-input-s3-2.0.3/lib
/logstash/inputs/s3.rb", :line=>"78", :method=>"register"}←[0m
←[32mPipeline started {:level=>:info, :file=>"/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/
gems/logstash-core-2.0.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"89", :method=>"
run"}←[0m
Logstash startup completed
```

Can someone explain why this is happening.

Permissions on my bucket are open to everyone so I don't think it is that, Also I can hit my bucket with post man and the data is returned.

**postman**

[image]

**Curl**

[image]

What am I doing wrong or not getting.

Your help and advise is much appreciated.

G

Comment: The error message "Plugin not defined in namespace" makes me think the s3 input plugin is not installed.